# UITextView line spacing goes back to default when the .text value is changed

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview, spacing

On the attributes inspector, I set `.text` attribute in an `UITextView` tab as 'attributed' and then changed 'Line' value as 1.5.

When a new value is assigned to .text field in the `UITextView`, the line spacing is set back.

[image]

The left one is the view controller shown in `main.storyboard`, and the right one is the result after assigning `String` value in the `UITextView`, run in the simulator.

Is there like a constraint or something for me to fix the line spacing value after changing `.text`? I think it should be managed by codes..

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 40
let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style]
aboutNeyong.attributedText =
NSAttributedString(string: aboutNeyong.text!, attributes:attributes)
```

The code above is what I added after the assigning statement.

Comment: show how you are setting text ?

Comment: are you setting myTextView.text = something or myTextView.attributedText = something ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal it is like `UITextView.text = String()`;

Comment: the original statement contains something else which returns a `String` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the maximum and minimum height

example :

`style.maximumLineHeight = 10
style.minimumLineHeight = 10`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "attributedText" field of the UITextField rather than the "text" field. Make sure you pass in an attributed string with the desired spacing:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 15; // Desired line spacing here
NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = @{ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle };

textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your new string here!" attributes:attrsDictionary];
```

Comment: I editted the question; Can you check why the added statements do not make any changes? It does not change even with the code above.